# show child after parent hover transition

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, transition

I have a problem here. I need the "sidebar-buttons" to appear after increasing the parent element's size by the hover.
[gif w/ my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wjwo.gif)

buttons have display none and after I hovering my sidebar-list-item their display change to flex, so I need this change appear after changing sidebar-list-item height and background.

here is my code:

- html:

```
<div class="sidebar-list-item">
    <div class="sidebar-main-items">
        <div>Стретч-плёнки</div>
        <img
            src="./assets/icons/sidebar/paper-icon.svg"
            width="32"
            alt="paper icon"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-buttons">
        <button class="sidebar-button-buy" onclick="#">Купить</button>
        <button class="sidebar-button-how" onclick="#">Как выбрать?</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

- css:

```
.sidebar-list-item {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar-list-item:hover {
    display: block;
    min-height: 114px;
    background-color: #ffca3a;
}

.sidebar-list-item:hover .sidebar-buttons {
    display: flex;
}

.sidebar-list-item:hover .sidebar-main-items img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: did you use the transition-delayed property?

Comment: @JeetViramgama yep, try to add it in .sidebar-list-item:hover .sidebar-buttons and its didn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is animate the height of it.

First, set the heigth of content as auto.
Second, in buttons container, set max-height:0 and overflow:hidden.
Third, animate the buttons container to max-height:200px.

What happens?
The css will animation will take 400ms to reach 500px even if the container is smaller, so consider testing smaller values so the button animation doesn't finish before the main container animation.

**Edit:** Updated the snippet, added the transition-delay property on button animation to run 500ms after container animation.

```css
.sidebar-list-item {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding:10px 0;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}

.sidebar-list-item:hover {
    transition-delay: 00ms;
    background-color: #ffca3a;
    height:60px;
}

.sidebar-list-item:hover .sidebar-main-items img {
    opacity: 1;
} 

.sidebar-list-item:hover .sidebar-buttons {
    max-height:150px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}

.sidebar-buttons{
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-list-item">
    <div class="sidebar-main-items">
        <div>Стретч-плёнки</div>
        <img
            src="./assets/icons/sidebar/paper-icon.svg"
            width="32"
            height="32"
            alt="paper icon"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-buttons">
        <button class="sidebar-button-buy" onclick="#">Купить</button>
        <button class="sidebar-button-how" onclick="#">Как выбрать?</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no bro, I need child (sidebar-buttons) to appear after parent end his hover transition

Comment: @gftx Updated the snippet, added the transition-delay property on button animation to run 500ms after container animation.

Comment: it is almost what I need to do, but no. I need the buttons to appear 500ms after the height has increased to the end

Comment: So, just set the height of the container on normal and :hover state, updated the snippet.